# Improve code - difference between rows in R

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:8, x2=8:1, x3=11:18, x4=c(2,4,10,0,1,1,9,12))
df$x4_dif <- c(0, diff(df$x4))
df$x2_dif <- c(0, diff(df$x2))
df$x3_dif <- c(0, diff(df$x3))
```

How can I reduce the number of lines in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(across(x2:x4, ~c(0, diff(.x)), .names = '{col}_dif'))
df

#  ID x2 x3 x4 x2_dif x3_dif x4_dif
#1  1  8 11  2      0      0      0
#2  2  7 12  4     -1      1      2
#3  3  6 13 10     -1      1      6
#4  4  5 14  0     -1      1    -10
#5  5  4 15  1     -1      1      1
#6  6  3 16  1     -1      1      0
#7  7  2 17  9     -1      1      8
#8  8  1 18 12     -1      1      3
```

Or `lapply` in base R -

```
cols <- paste0('x', 2:4)
df[paste0(cols, '_dif')] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) c(0, diff(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could subtract with the `lag` value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(x2:x4, ~ .x - lag(.x, default = first(.x)), .names = "{.col}_dif"))
  ID x2 x3 x4 x2_dif x3_dif x4_dif
1  1  8 11  2      0      0      0
2  2  7 12  4     -1      1      2
3  3  6 13 10     -1      1      6
4  4  5 14  0     -1      1    -10
5  5  4 15  1     -1      1      1
6  6  3 16  1     -1      1      0
7  7  2 17  9     -1      1      8
8  8  1 18 12     -1      1      3
```